# How do I add external tools to eclipse project context menu?

Tags: eclipse

I have a few commands that I've defined as "External Tools" in eclipse. I would like to run said commands against one or more projects. Right now, I have to click on the project in package explorer, move my mouse to the 'Run' menu, move down to External Tools, and then click on the tool I want to run.

Ideally I would like to do this from the right click context menu in "Package Explorer". That is I'd like to right click on the project, select "external tools" and then select the command I want. How do I customize eclipse to do this?

I tried looking around "Customize Perspective..." menu, but couldn't find anything that would help.